# Why are images in a Flatlist sometimes not rendering?

Tags: ios, image, react-native, rendering, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to fix my Flatlist of images, sometimes when I load the screen all the images load and sometimes a random number of images load, and I have no idea why. Any suggestions on how to get all the images to consistently render all of the time?

The image source is from a external url.

I've added a gif on the issue. It shows me switching screens, and the different results I get everytime I return to the Flatlist grid of images.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1u3b.jpg

I've tried the flatlist prop removeClippedSubviews={true} and {false}.

```
renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
  return(
    //console.log(item)
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.toggleView.bind(this, index)} > 
      <View >
      <Image source={{uri: item.images.thumbnail.url, cache:'force-cache'}} style={styles.item} resizeMode={"resize"}/>      
      </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
   ) 
 }


render(){
return(
        <FlatList
        ref={(ref) => { this._flatList = ref; }}
        data={this.props.profileMedia}
        onScroll={this.handleScroll}
        renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
        numColumns={3}
        ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
        ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
        columnWrapperStyle={{justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}
        contentOffset = {{x: 0, y:this.props.scrollPosition}}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        initialNumToRender={12}
      />
  )
 }
```

Comment: iOS or android? There was a problem on android a while ago, not sure if it has been fixed already. A workaround was to preload the images with width and height of 0, so they are not visible, but they are available for display.

Comment: It's iOS, but i'll look into this anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the resolution of the images, React Native usually has issues with garbage collection of images with large resolutions.

Comment: The images are only 150 x 150 so I don't think this is the issue unfortunately